# How to unit test structure of returned object from method call?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to unit test for structure of the object, I am making call to method `getResults()` and it returns me an `object` has properties like:

`double mathMarks, double scienceMarks, double historyMarks`, now how do I test the returned object's structure in my `Junit` class?

i have `vo` where `double mathMarks, double scienceMarks, double historyMarks` are defined, I am not sure how can I check the structure of the returned object in my test class? Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "check the structure"? What exactly is it that you want to know about the object that's being returned?

Comment: @Anthony- I am new to unit testing and so I want to check that object contains all the properties that I am looking and so I said structure as I was not sure about to put it out otherwise.

Comment: If you call a method that returns an instance of the VO class, it can either return an instance of the VO class (which you can be sure will contain all of the instance variables/fields/properties [whatever you want to call them] of the VO class without explicitly testing) or `null`.

Comment: @Anthony-So you are saying that there is not point of testing for structure of `MarketData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you would normally have an interface or a common super class which specifies the required members. You could then test with `assertTrue(a instanceof SomeClass)` Note that this test fails even if the returned objects has the required members but doesn't implement/extend SomeClass.

If you want/have to work with fields, you can use reflection to check for the presence of the fields and there type.

A third alternative would be to use a language like groovy for your test. It would allow you to write code accessing the code, no matter if they are actually there or not. At least I think this should be possible, but since I never actually worked with groovy I can't provide any details.

In order to choose the correct approach, the question is: how does the client code access the fields/members. Your tests should use the same approach.

Comment: Testing `assertTrue(a instanceof SomeClass)` is it best practice? What are the pros and cons of doing something like this?

Comment: @Jens-Can you give me an example of second alternative of using reflection?

Comment: You can find lots of examples in the official tutorials. E.g. here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html

Comment: Best practice? I'd say the whole scenario you put up smells a little fishy. So it is really hard to tell. But if you have a solution with reflection and one without I'd prefer the one without reflection. This I do consider a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Since java is strongly typed, and not a dynamic language, this type of testing is not really needed.  You should have some sort of ResultClass, with its own tests, so the structure of that class is implicitly tested for you.

If your method can return subclasses, it is ok to test that the returned class is the right type based on the input, but those subclasses should have their own unit tests which verifies their structure functionality.

Also note that if your results class has a method like `getScienceMarks`, you should verify that the returned value is correct based on the input to the method that returned the results.  Here you are making sure that the class you are testing is performing properly.  It is implicitly verifying the structure of the result class; i.e. that it has the appropriate methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, use Hamcrest:

```
MyPojo pojo = ...getResults();
assertThat(pojo, allOf(
    hasProperty("mathMarks", equalTo(123),
    hasProperty("scienceMarks", equalTo(321),
    ...));
```

The hasProperty matcher verifies that a given object has the specific JavaBean properties with the given values (value matchers are optional).

Comment: Can we do it without using any kind of external libraries?

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you're trying to test. If you're not using a library, wouldn't you just check that `pojo.getMathMarks.equals(123)`?